# не работает ondrop javascript

Tags: javascript, события

событие ondrop не работает и не выдаёт команду в консоль по другому вызвать событие нельзя ибо элементы багуют

```
<div class="drop_zone" onclick="click_inp(1)" ondragleave="drag_leave(1, event)" ondragenter="on_drug(1, event)" ondrop="drop_el(1, event)">
    <span class = "drop_zone_text">Drop file here</span>
    <input type="file" name="filename" class="drop_zone_input" id="1" onchange="">
</div>
```

JAVA

```
  function drop_el(i, event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    let inputElement = document.getElementById(i);
    let dropZoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop_zone");
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Странно но у меня появляется Hi в консоли.

```js
 function drop_el(i, event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    let inputElement = document.getElementById(i);
    let dropZoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop_zone");
    console.log("hi");
}
```

```html
<div class="drop_zone" ondrop="drop_el(1, event)">
    <span class = "drop_zone_text">Drop file here</span>
    <input type="file" name="filename" class="drop_zone_input" id="1" onchange="">
</div>
```

вот скриин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хмм у меня в 2 браузерах не работает(

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrop.asp не все поддерживают его

Comment: понял он почему то обращается к скрытому элементу input хотя нужно к div ток я всё равно хз как это фиксить

Answer (score 0):

проблема в отсутвтвии события dragover почему то в этом, не очень хорошем языке, ondrop для div без него не работает